# TypeError: open_window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Недавно открыл для себя **Python**, в частности библиотеку **Tkinter**. Хочу сделать окна авторизации и регистрации для своего приложения. Сначала думал просто прописать в коде логин и пароль для доступа, но потом решил, что лучше будет сделать окно регистрации. Приложение регистрирует пользователя, запоминает его логин и пароль и далее запускает саму программу (в приведённом ниже коде в калькулятор).

При запуске приложения открывается окно **авторизации**, где пользователю предлагается ввести свой логин и пароль. Так же есть возможность регистрации. Программа запускается, но при нажатии на кнопку **"Регистрация"** вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\apaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: open_window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Не могу никак пофиксить, прошу помощи у опытных программистов.
Спасибо!

```
#импорт всех нужных библиотек
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import Toplevel
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import os
#настройки главного окна
window=Tk()
window.title('Авторизация')
window.geometry('380x300')
window["bg"]="grey25"
window.resizable(width=True, height=True)
#настройки всплывающего окна
class Reg(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        window.label = tk.Label(self, text="Пожалуйста, введите данные для регистрации")
        window.button = tk.Button(self, text="Закрыть", command=self.destroy)
        window.label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        window.button.pack(pady=5, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app = App()
            app.mainloop()

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



def open_window(self):
    Reg = Reg(self)
    Reg.grab_set()
#получение логина и пароля с окна ввода
def get_E_log():
    log=E_log.get()
def get_E_pas():
    pas=E_pas.get()
#проверка логина и пароля на правильность
def click1():
    if E_log.get()=='admin' and E_pas.get()=='123':
        messagebox.showinfo("Сообщение", "Доступ получен")
        os.system("start calc")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Сообщение", "Отказано в доступе\nТы кто, дядя?")
#св-ва переменных
log=StringVar()
pas=StringVar()
#Логин
L_log=Label(window, text='Введите логин: ', font=("consolas", 15), bg="grey25", fg="white", padx=1, pady=1)
L_log.grid(column=0, row=0)
E_log=Entry(window, width=16, justify=CENTER, textvariable=log)
E_log.grid(column=1, row=0)
#Пароль
L_pas=Label(window, text=' Введите пароль: ', font=("consolas", 15), bg="grey25", fg="white", padx=1, pady=1)
L_pas.grid(column=0, row=1)
E_pas=Entry(window, width=16, justify=CENTER, textvariable=pas)
E_pas.grid(column=1, row=1)
#Кнопка подтверждения
B_accept=Button(window, text="Подтвердить", font=("consolas", 10), bg="black", fg="white", padx=1, pady=1, command=click1)
B_accept.grid(column=2, row=2)
#Кнопка регистрации
B_reg=Button(window, text="Регистрация", font=("consolas", 10), bg="black", fg="white", padx=1, pady=1, command=open_window)
B_reg.grid(column=2, row=3)
#Ожидание  взаимодействия
window.mainloop()
```

[image: Интерфейс окна авторизации]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: исправьте пробелы в коде, возможно вы некорректно скопировали код

Comment: Еще... у вас форматирование полетело и код стало сложно понимать, добавьте отступы, чтобы код был как у вас :)

Comment: @gil9red я думаю оно не полетело, просто код такой)

Comment: @gil9red, извиняюсь за предоставленные неудобства. Спасибо за совет, учту в будущем.

Comment: @Whynot_46, ничего страшного, спасибо за содействие :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `open_window` не метод, а просто функция, поэтому в нее при вызове не передается никакой `self`.
Тут несколько вариантов решения:

1. Передавать явно родительское окно
2. Сделать эту функцию методом какого-то класса, и вызывать от объекта этого класса. Но тут не понятно что это за класс - явно не App, потому что он по логике вашей программы должен создаваться только после нажатия на кнопку.

Поэтому, делаем по первому варианту:

```
def open_window(parent):
    reg = Reg(parent)  # Не называем переменную так же как класс
    reg.grab_set()

...

B_reg=Button(window, text="Регистрация", font=("consolas", 10), bg="black", fg="white", padx=1, pady=1,
             command=lambda: open_window(window))
```